# I keep getting the error java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileOutputStream

Tags: serialization

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        Vector<Vector> tableData = model.getDataVector();
        
        //Saving of object in a file
        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("StudentFile.bin");
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(file);


            
            // Method for serialization of object
            output.writeObject(file);

            output.close();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        new ComputerScience_IA_UI().setVisible(true);
    
        this.dispose();//to close the current jframe 
    }
```

this is my code

I wanted it to save data in a file
But every time it always gave me the same error java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code

```
try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("StudentFile.bin");
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        
        Vector<Vector> tableData = (Vector<Vector>)input.readObject();
        
        input.close();
        file.close();
        
        
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableData.size(); i++) {
            Vector row = tableData.get(i);
            model.addRow(new Object [] {row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3), row.get(4), row.get(5)});
        }
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```